# Using .env files for unit testing with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, environment-variables, jestjs

Is it possible to load environment variables from an env file for unit testing purposes in Jest? I'm looking to run a series of tests on it like so:

```
// unit tests for env file
describe('env', () => {
    it('should have a client id', () => {
        expect(process.env.CLIENT_ID).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a client secret', () => {
        expect(process.env.CLIENT_SECRET).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a host', () => {
        expect(process.env.HOST).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a scope', () => {
        expect(process.env.SCOPE).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a response type', () => {
        expect(process.env.RESPONSE_TYPE).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should have a redirect uri', () => {
        expect(process.env.REDIRECT_URI).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Currently, all the above tests will fail, stating that the variables are undefined. Initially I was using a mocha/chai setup, which allowed me to just load all of my env variables via the use of dotenv. This involved running all unit tests through webpack and worked fine.

However, from reading the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html) Jest doesn't run tests through webpack; instead modules are mocked out via moduleNameMapper. This works fine for everything else, but I can't get the env file variables to load. So far I've tried using the setupFiles option to a js file that calls dotenv.config with the path of the env file given to it like so:

```
// setup file for jest
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './env' });
```

This didn't work, so I've now resorted to using just a .env.js file for unit tests and passing this file into the setupFiles option instead. However, for maintainability, and to keep it working with webpack for production, I'd like to just keep it all in one file. Here's an extract of how the .env.js file looks for reference

```
// .env.js extract example
process.env.PORT = 3000;
process.env.HOST = 'localhost';
process.env.CLIENT_ID = 'your client id';
process.env.REDIRECT_URI = 'your callback endpoint';
```

Comment: Using Jest's setupFiles with `dotenv.config(...)` is the way to go for sure. What was the error you ran into with that approach? I'd double check to make sure your paths are correct. I use `dotenv-safe` on a project, and initialize in the jest setup file almost exactly as you have it.

Comment: Yes that was pretty much it, thanks. Can't check your comment as the answer,so I've added it in just now.

Comment: docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your top config path using `./` is relative from the point of injection, it's likely your test suite might be inside a folder named `test` which causes it to not be found when running your unit tests. `dotenv.config();` Uses global injection strategy which is similar to absolute pathing.

Comment: Module ./__tests__/setup-test.ts in the setupFiles option was not found.

Answer (score 72):

None of these worked for me, but I found a great article on [configuring dotenv by default in Jest](https://medium.com/better-things-digital/using-dotenv-with-jest-7e735b34e55f) in the package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --setupFiles dotenv/config"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, there's no need to make a separate setup file. If you have an existing `jest.config.js` you can add it there as well:

`module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ['dotenv/config']
}`

Comment: if you are like me trying to find a way to change the dotenv config path to use `.env.test` instead of `.env`, the answer is `DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.test jest` when you run jest.

Comment: @Nikordaris I tried in the same way as you mentioned in the comment. It just doesn't work for me. `dotenv_config_path=.envs/local.env jest --setupFiles dotenv/config` This is what I have configured for the `npm test` command but on the terminal, it throws the following error `'dotenv_config_path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 66):

You can load the env files for all your tests like this. The setup file will be executed once per each test file that is loaded.

*jest.config.js*:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFiles: ["<rootDir>/test/setup-tests.ts"],
};
```

*test/setup-tests.ts*:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env.test' });
```

Answer (score 27):

I found another solution to run jest with dotenv using a custom `.env` file. In my case, I run jest using NPM scripts.

1. Setup jest to use dotenv (as shown in other solutions)

```sh
jest --setupFiles=dotenv/config
```

2. Add the custom `.env` file (here: `.env.test`) using a environment variable

```sh
DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=.env.test jest --setupFiles=dotenv/config
```

This can be added to the script part of your `package.json` directly

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=.env.test jest --setupFiles=dotenv/config"
}
```

Comment: very clean method, i pick this way

Comment: you'll also have to configure webstorm as well under the 'debug configuration' to also add `--setupFiles` to the debug jest command as well

Answer (score 19):

(2020) According to the docs of `dotenv`, you shouldn't use `dotenv` in testing (more on that later). If you need some globally available values, there are multiple ways to set it up, for instance:

1. setup global variables with jest:

```
// jest.config.json:
{
  "globals": {
    "a": 1
  }
}
// test:
test('global vars', () => {
  expect(global.a).toBe(1);
});
```

2. Use a setup file:

```js
// jest.config.json:
{
  "setupFiles": ['./jestSetup.js'],
}
// jestSetup.js:
process.env.FOO = 'FOO';
global.bar = 'bar';
// test:
test('env vars and global vars', () => {
  expect(process.env.FOO).toBe('FOO');
  expect(global.bar).toBe('bar');
});
```

3. use [globalSetup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) and [globalTeardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalteardown-string):
   Very similar to 2.

The reason against using `dotenv` is that values in `process.env` are meant to be different in different deployments, which are set by the environment, not by you. If a variable doesn't change in different environments, then it's not an environmental variable, it's just a global variable that you set manually. The dotenv doc further points to [the 12 factor app](https://12factor.net/config) which is a good read.

Comment: Great answer. I would add also that having tests for environment variables passed might be useless

Comment: I don't see anything stating to not use during testing.

Comment: @AlfredoR It says to not have more than one, and gives `.env.test` as an explicit example of what not to do.

Comment: @MEMark if you stick to something not being a standard you end up limiting your options. the rule is good for deployment envs but I don't see harm using diff .env files for diff local development purposes such as unit or integration testing.

Comment: @AlfredoR personally I tend to agree with you. But the article linked to does not share this view.

Comment: Downvoted due to the opening statement of this answer

Answer (score 7):

Just adding  `setupFiles: ['dotenv/config']` in jest.config.ts worked for me.

Useful article found [here](https://tekloon.dev/using-dotenv-with-jest).

Full setup:

```js
const jestConfig = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
        },
    },
    verbose: true,
    testMatch: ['<rootDir>/test/**/*(*.)+(test).+(tsx)'],
    setupFiles: [
        'dotenv/config'
    ],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test/setupTests.ts'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'tsx'],
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: 'target/coverage',
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/**/*.tsx',
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^.+\\.(css)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
        '^.+\\.(png|svg|pdf|jpg|jpeg)$': 'jest-transform-stub'
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$'],
};

export default jestConfig;
```

Answer (score 6):

So the issue require changing this:

```
dotenv.config({ path: './env' });
```

to :

```
dotenv.config();
```

Why it didn't pick it up I have no idea, but just leaving the defaults worked.

Comment: aren't you missing a point? `dotenv.config({ path: './.env' });`

Comment: oh you, such pun 

Comment: Thanks for giving me the hint on path option, but the file is `.env`. By default it's `{ path: '.env' }`. I have used `{ path: '.env.test' }` to load custom testing env.

Answer (score 3):

I am little late, but hope this helps for someone who are looking for making dotenv work. This is just an extended flavor of what @DavidDehghan said.
So add a setup file to be run before any jest configuration like as David said

Now making sure  dotenv load for the platform to resolve the relative path, please make use of `path` module to resolve the folder

```
import * as  dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';

dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname + './../config/testFolder/.env') });
```

Now in your spec file you can test if the `process.env` variable contains the values loaded from `.env` file in `testFolder`

```
describe('Test suite - testing app service', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    console.log('coming inside beforeAll', process.env.LCp);

  });
});
```

Comment: Asking OP to install additional modules or libraries when not necessary isn't a good way to approach solution.

Answer (score 3):

Combining a few answers here into a simple solution: add [`dotenv-flow`](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow) and use it in your test script:

`jest --setupFiles dotenv-flow/config`

Answer (score 2):

I'am using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and I have the below structure in my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=test.env jest --setupFiles dotenv/config "
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "bail": true
  }
}
```

This basically allows me to use `dotenv` with `jest`, and where I can mention the exact `.env` file name or path.

Answer (score 0):

I keep seeing a dependency on `dotenv`...

If you're trying to do this without a installing a package, simply read the text file and load it into `process.env`:

1. Create a `loadEnvironment.js`:

```
let fs = require('fs')

let envFile = fs.readFileSync("path/to/env/file").toString()

let envFileLines = envFile.split("\n")

for (let line of envFileLines) {
    let [key, value] = line.split("=");
    process.env[key] = value
}
```

2. Add your file to the setupFile option, for example, in jest.config.js, add: `setupFiles: ["./loadEnvironment.js"],`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`nx`](https://nx.dev) to run your tests with a command like:

`nx run-many --target=test`

Then `nx` completely overrides `dotenv` with its own set of [environment variables](https://nx.dev/recipes/tips-n-tricks/define-environment-variables#setting-environment-variables).

If you have these files in your project root:

```
.env
.env.test
```

In this case `.env.test` is accepted by `nx` and will override `.env`, but if you rename `.env.test` to anything else and set that in the `dotenv` `path` config, that will be overridden by an `.env` file.

I think if you have **no** `.env` (or any others file recognised by `nx`) then potentially your `dotenv` path will work.