# Dotenv loads envs but Jest doesn't read them

Tags: testing, jestjs, environment-variables, dotenv

**BACKGROUND**

I'm using `process.env.<ENV NAME>` to set variables in some classes. I need to set them in the tests for the class variables to be set otherwise the test fails.

Currently, I'm setting the variables in a `beforeAll()` hook. However, there are many test files in which I'll have to set these envs. I don't want to replicate this code throughout all these files if I don't have to.

I decided it would be a good idea to set them up prior to each test through a Jest set-up file. In `jest.config.js` I added `setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jestSetupTest.js']`. Inside this file I added `require('dotenv').config()`. The `.env` file is in the root directory.

I've got test files in a couple of different directories: `./src/graphql/__tests__` and `./src/utils/__tests__`.

**PROBLEM**

The envs are being set but they are not being read by any of the Jest tests that are running.

**ATTEMPTED**

I looked into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092607/using-dotenv-path-with-jest) which got me as far as being able to set-up the env vars, but it has nothing about issues using them.

I've added `require('dotenv').config()` to the test files that use the envs, but that still doesn't work. This surprised me I thought at least this would set the envs.

I set `--debug` on Jest but that doesn't show whether envs were set or not.

**QUESTIONS**

Does anyone know what is going on? Or how I can further diagnose this issue?

I get the impression envs can be set and used in Jest tests, as per the SO post above. Why am I not able to use them? Could it be a config issue with the way my files are set-up?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you already found a solution. I had my own struggles getting tests to run with the env variables from an `.env.test` file for my 'create react app'. In the end, all that was necessary was to add the path to the desired env-file in my cmd line scripts in my package.json-file:

```
    "test": "react-scripts test dotenv_config_path=.env.test",
```

No further configuration was needed.

But there could be some presets going on coming from 'create react app'. I am not entirely sure about this.

So, to get to your question: Maybe you could just put your env variables in a separate file witch you then load through your run-test-script.