# using .env.local with playwright

Tags: next.js, playwright

I'm setting up some first playwright tests for my nextjs project. I already have environment variables in my `.env.local` and I'd like to pull them into my test env.

I'm looking at the documentation and I see that I can add `require("dotenv").config();` to my `playwright.config.js` but nothing is happening when I do that (the scripts are erroring out because of `undefined`.

I tried both calling `process.env.foo` directly within the script, and also adding a `use: {foo: process.env.FOO}` clause to the `playwright.config.js` and moving my variables to `.env` file instead of `.env.local` but nothing worked.

Help would be much appreciated! thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading [using dotenv path with JEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092607/using-dotenv-path-with-jest) I found the solution is to configure the `require` statement:

1. install the dotenv package (the one that comes with next.js isn't loaded)

```
npm install --save-dev dotenv
```

2. In `.env.local` - set the vars

```js
FOO=bar
```

3. In playwright.config.js - set which env file to use

```js
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env.local" });
console.log(process.env.FOO); // prints "bar"
```

4. In a spec

```js
test("env", async ({ page }) => {
  console.log(process.env.FOO); // also prints "bar"
})
```