# Fetch is not defined with firebase and jest

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, jestjs

I am trying to run tests with jest on my Next.js project. However I can't because I always get:

```
 src/lib/utils/item.utils.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

      32 | export const firebaseConfig = {
      33 |   apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
    > 34 |   authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
         |                    ^
      35 |   databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      36 |   projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      37 |   storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORAGE_BUCKET,

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/functions/src/index.ts:28:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase/functions/dist/index.cjs.js:5:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/firebase/firebase.config.tsx:34:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/utils/item.utils.ts:27:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lib/utils/item.utils.test.tsx:6:20)
```

I tried installing node-fetch, whatwg-fetch and set global.fetch but nothing worked.

Comment: What is your Node.js version? If you are below 18, `fetch` wont be available.

Comment: Yeah its node 20.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to install (which you have done):

```
"whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
"jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3"
```

then in your jest.setup.js add this at the top of the file:

```
// Makes fetch available globally to prevent a Warning
import 'whatwg-fetch';
global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');

fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({testing: true})); // mock every fetchCall in all tests with this default value
```

In your tests you can then do:

```
import fetch from 'jest-fetch-mock';
fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(null)); // or whatever you want as response, for that specific test.
```

If you have done all this and are still running in to issues, I think there is an issue with your setup or combination of libraries. So to get help you'll need to share the relevant parts of jest.setup, jest.config, versions used and testFile.

Comment: This works! I made a slight altercation with `fetchMock.enableMocks()
fetchMock.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({ testing: true }))` in the setup file. Do I need to make a .env.test file or something because none of my env variables show up during jest.

Comment: Nice! I think the .env file is a differnt issue. I don't use and environment variables in my test, because I have mocked everything that uses them. But maybe You have to do something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259025/using-env-files-for-unit-testing-with-jest . Seems like .env is not used automatically, you'll have to configure it.