# NodeJS -env-file-.env with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have been using the nodejs --env-file-.env flag to load environment variables into process.env variable as per this documentation: https://nodejs.org/en/learn/command-line/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs

Is it possible to pass this parameter to jest so that .env file is read by node? Unfortunately you cannot pass it in NODE_OPTIONS.

All the other questions on jest and environment variables suggest using the setupFiles option discussed here:

[Using .env files for unit testing with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259025/using-env-files-for-unit-testing-with-jest)